# Loop through a list and pass single item to SQL Update Query with Python

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I will try and explain this the best I can. I have a list of lets say ids that I can store in a python list, I need to be able to loop through the list and pass the single id to a update query for SQL.

Here is what I have, I have two separate databases which are hosted on two separate servers with a table in each, one has a column containing a voicemail value and the other needs to be updated with that value based on the ID.

I have a working piece of code right now but you need to provide the ID manually, I would like to store all the IDS in a list and then just loop through it.

my code so far:

```
def add_vm():
    ID = input("ID: ").upper()
    checkTwo = 1
    while checkTwo == 1:
        if len(ID) == 6:
            checkTwo = 0
        elif len(ID) != 6:
            print("\n[bold red]ID entered is incorrect")
            ID = input("\nID: ")
    promote_tag = "My tag here"
    getVoicemail = """select VOICEMAIL from Database1 where ID = ?"""
    cursorTwo.execute(getVoicemail, ID)
    for row in cursorTwo:
        row_to_list5 = [elem for elem in row]
        voicemail = str(row_to_list5[0])
    voicemailFormat = '+1' + voicemail
    update_Query1 = """update table1 set column1 = ?, promote_type = 1, voicemail = ? where ID = ?"""
    cursor.execute(update_Query1, promote_tag, voicemailFormat, ID)
    conn.commit()
    print("Record updated")


while True:
    add_vm()
```

What I would like to do is figure out if its possible to take all my ids that I have and just create a python list then somehow loop through that list providing the id to both the getVoicemail and also updateQuery lines

Comment: You seem to be using the word "database" incorrect herely, you don't `UPDATE` a database, nor to you `SELECT` from one (like you have in your statement in `getVoicemail`). A database is something you *connect* to, and contains objects such as tables, views, procedures, etc. It is the table(s) you want to `UPDATE`, not a database.

Comment: Yes apologies, I meant I that I have two tables that are on seperate databases. One table in database 1 that has the value I retrieve and one table in database 2 that I run an UPDATE on with the value retrieved from database1 @Larnu

Comment: Why not use an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN` then? Why do you want to do 1 `UPDATE` per value, rather than just a *single* `UPDATE` for **all** the values? The former will be *significantly* slower than the latter.

Comment: I did try to experiment with that but these databases are on different servers. @Larnu

Comment: That is important information to the question, and should be included in it.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post to include that. @Larnu